# Cannot find module browser' in protractor.conf.js?

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

I am trying to add the following line

```
  browser.waitForAngularVariable(false);
```

in onPrepare() as follows,

```
 onPrepare() {

     browser.waitForAngularVariable(false);

 }
```

When i run it says 'cannot find module browser'

Comment: Sounds like protractor isn't installed correctly. How are you starting protractor?

Comment: rimraf e2e/e2ereport && $(npm bin)/protractor e2e/protractor.conf.js

Comment: what is `waitForAngularVariable`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is `waitForAngularVariable`. Assuming your are trying to ask protractor to wait until the angular elements to load.

Try the below one to do the same

`browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);`

Hope it helps you